# Trying to Write a Script to Kill Processes based on niceness

Tags: bash, kill, nice

I am trying to write a script in bash that will kill any of my own processes (and run indefinitely) if those processes have a niceness value of 4 or lower. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

```
while [true]
do 
    ps -l | grep -w sleep| grep -v grep > proc.txt
    for i in proc.txt pidNice=$(awk'//{if ($6<=4 {print $3}}')
    kill -15 $pidNice <proc.txt 
done
```

Comment: It would be easier to stop, un-nice,  processes from being started. This can be done by setting the login shell to be nice of 4.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to avoid killing `ps` and the shell that is running script, not just `grep`.
2. `for` has no `do` or `done`
3. What is `<proc.txt` for in `kill` line?
4. It is easier to to start them, than to kill them.